# Install opengl driver on RHEL5.7

Tags: rhel, software-installation, opengl

A user is using a software called "HyperLynx - LineSim" to plot a graph.  When he wants to view the graph, there's this error "Failed to run PowerScope: OpenGL is not installed".

[image]

The machine is running RHEL5.7, and it using embedded graphic card.

```
# lspci -v|grep -i vga
01:06.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Rage XL (rev 27) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

I googled but doesn't get anywhere further.  Does anyone know how to fix this error and where I can download the OpenGL rpm for this OS?

Comment: install mesa-dri-drivers package. Make sure that hardware acceleration is enabled: glxinfo | grep "direct rendering"

Comment: Thanks mzet. I can't find this rpm for RHEL5 though.  Any URL that you can share?  I have the following installed but it doesn't fix the error.

mesa-libGLU-devel-6.5.1-7.8.el5
mesa-libGL-6.5.1-7.8.el5
mesa-libGL-6.5.1-7.8.el5
mesa-libOSMesa-6.5.1-7.8.el5
mesa-libGL-devel-6.5.1-7.8.el5
mesa-libOSMesa-devel-6.5.1-7.8.el5
mesa-libGLU-6.5.1-7.8.el5
mesa-libGLU-6.5.1-7.8.el5
mesa-libOSMesa-6.5.1-7.8.el5
mesa-libOSMesa-devel-6.5.1-7.8.el5